# Gitlab jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, gitlab

I am using jenkins as CI server and Gitlab as Codebase both are running into two serpent docker containers.

I have created CICD pipeline into jenkins and gitlab repo. also setup webhook which working fine. Now I want to integrate jenkins from gitlab and inserted required details but it showing 401 error while test. please note entered details are verified and credentials are working.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seUmL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4ia0W.png)

Answer (score 0):

401 indicates that the request is *unauthorized*. So, stated another way: your credentials are correctly set, but the credentials do not have the appropriate permission needed.

You should make sure your API keys are generated with appropriate scope and/or that the user account associated with the keys have appropriate permission.

Comment: You should make sure your API keys are generated with appropriate scope and/or that the user account associated with the keys have appropriate permission.,  i am not able to understand what are you trying to say . please explain in layman language.

Answer (score 0):

Even properly generated user/api for integration will not overrun project advanced settings itself if configured:

[image]

Unless this field is blank, integration would not work :(